# Relationship between LD_LIBRARY_PATH and lib-dynload in Python

Tags: python

Can anyone explain the relationship between the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the lib-dynload directory works in Python on a Unix machine.

The reason I ask is because at my place of employment, we have a network install of Python that works across several unix machines (Don't ask why, its a bunch of odd political oddities.) It works fine for most of the systems which are older, but on the newer systems, it runs into problems when people try to use the tkinter framework (since those machines have newer versions of the underlying libraries installed.)

I did some poking around, and inside the lib-dynload directory there is another library file which seems to just direct Python which library to use for tkinter stuff.

Doing some fiddling, I found a way to bypass the problem (essentially, placing the new versions of the library at the front of the user's LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to solve the problem. I assume it works because it's finding this version of the library before the version in the lib-dynload folder, but it breaks if you attempt to do so on one of the older machines), but this is really an inelegant solution.